# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'getPosts')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, graphql, mern

I am a beginner, and i'm currently following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1mdAPFq2Os) by freecodecamp. And I  got two errors, one for the homepage:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getPosts')

and the other one at login and register page:

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'extensions')

Here are the screenshots of the errors,

[Home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czuR0.png)
[Login/Register page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wduxc.png)

So I cloned the github repo and tried to run it, and I got the same error.

Here is the link to the github repo: https://github.com/hidjou/classsed-graphql-mern-apollo/tree/master

Comment: did you install the dependencies ?

Comment: @Aggestor yes, i installed all of them.

Comment: can you please share the full errors?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @niiir I have uploaded the ss of the errors.

Comment: can you also share your getPost function from the util folder?